# Exact grep -f command in Linux

Tags: linux, shell, unix, grep

I have 2 txt files in Linux.

A.txt contents (each line will contain a number):

```
1
2
3
```

B.txt contents (each line will contain a number):

```
1
2
3
10
20
30
```

`grep -f A.txt B.txt` results below:

```
1
2
3
10
20
30
```

Is there a way to grep in such a way I will get only the exact match, i.e. not 10, 20, 30?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For exact match use `-x` switch

```
grep -x -f A.txt B.txt
```

**EDIT:** If you don't want grep's regex capabilities and need to treat search pattern as fixed-strings then use `-F` switch as:

```
grep -xF -f A.txt B.txt
```

```
     -x, --line-regexp
             Only input lines selected against an entire fixed string or regular expression are considered to be matching lines.
```

Comment: And add `-F` to disable metacharacters in the input. For example, `3.14` would also match `3124` without the `-F` aka `fgrep` option.

Comment: @tripleee: Thanks so much, I'm adding it to my answer.

Comment: @tripleee I think you mean that 3.14 would also match 3214, not 3124.

Comment: This was what I needed to filter out an exact name but not when it's a prefix.

Answer (score 4):

As anubhava pointed out, `grep -x` will match the whole line. there's another switch `-w` for matching word. So `grep -wf A.txt B.txt` will show matches if a word from `A.txt` matches with a word in `B.txt`

Answer (score 4):

Try adding the `-w` flag:

`grep -wf A.txt B.txt`

This will give you exact result which is under:
1
2
3

Thanks

```
     -w, --word-regexp
             The expression is searched for as a word (as if surrounded by ‘[[:<:]]’ and ‘[[:>:]]’; see re_format(7)).  This option has no effect if -x is also specified.
```

Answer (score -2):

you can try to identify the file name which contains different contents

```
  # cat a.txt
  1
  2
  3
  # cat b.txt
  1
  2
  3
  10
  20
  30
  # grep -L a.txt b.txt
  b.txt
```

Comment: The question is well written and specifically requires getting only the matching lines between the two files. Your answer does not cover that.